# Differentiating between the pronunciation of "woman" and "women"

Tags: pronunciation

> . . . woman . . . women . . . [[audio source]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/135)

*Women* is still easier to hear than *woman*. /w/ and /i/ have considerable different positions horizontally and vertically in IPA chart, but for *woman*, /w/ and /u/ have almost the same vertical positions. I hear /wəmən/ instead of /wumən/.

What do I have to know in order to hear the /wu/ sound?

Comment: What is your concern? If you hear a word, and don't mess it with another word, everything must be fine.

Comment: I'm certain I say /wəmən/ and not /wuman/. Maybe a dialect difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a description of how the sound is produced, [this](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/#) source is useful, but the audio examples there are not to my mind very distinctive.

For audio examples I recommend those provided in the [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/woman). There you may look up a variety of words employing a given sound—*woman*, *should*, *pull*, and so forth—and play clean pronunciations. And then you may look up words with contrasting sounds for comparison—*woo*, *do*, *pool*, for instance, then *but*, *mud*, *mull*.